# Jetpack Compose Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my app I'm getting crashlytics reports that some users are experiencing this crash

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Only VectorDrawables and rasterized asset types are supported ex. PNG, JPG
```

I've had this issue from time to time with Compose but only now is it recently getting more frequent. It seems to be a compose bug only as this affects random users and the drawable in question is never consistent.

Does anyone have a way to essentially try/catch the painterResource so I can at least stop the app crashing for users? I've built out the below Image Composable but unfortunately try catching in Composables is not allowed

```
@Composable
fun AppImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @DrawableRes resource: Int,
    colorFilter: ColorFilter? = null
) {
    Image(
        modifier = modifier,
        painter = painterResource(id = resource),
        contentDescription = null,
        colorFilter = colorFilter
    )
}
```

Comment: I am not sure , but may be the size of image is very large

Comment: Yes, it can be a issue and we can get an OutOfMemory. Try to search on Logs by some OutOfMemory.

Comment: It helped me to use `ImageVector.vectorResource` instead and rebuild the project.